# C, issue with asigning a value through a pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers, letter

Ok so I have written a little function to convert any capitals in a string into the lower case just for an exercise out of a book that I am learning C from.

Everything works fine other than assigning the value into a 'char' through a pointer.
Here is the code and everything compiles correctly but I get this runtime error "Unkown pseudo relocation protocol version %d." this is why I try and print the char that had the value changed through the pointer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*
----------------------------------------------
    CONVERTS UPPERCASE CHARACTERS TO LOWERCASE
----------------------------------------------
*/
 void lowercase(char * address, char text2){
    // used in the for loop
    int inc;
    // used as an index for text2Copy
    int inctwo = 0;
    // used in the for loop
    int length = strlen(text2);
    //used to copy the active character in text2
    char  text2Copy[length];

    for(inc = 0; inc <= length; inc++){
        //basicaly if character is a capital leter
        if(text2[inc] >= 'A' && text2[inc] <= 'Z'){
            //I plus 32 because each letter is 32 numbers away in 'ASCII'
            //therefore converting capital to lowercase
            text2Copy[inctwo] = text2[inc] + 32;
            //add one to help with indexing
            inctwo++;
        }
        //if the character is not a capital leter
        else{
            text2Copy[inctwo] = text2[inc];
            inctwo++;
        }
    }

    //*address = "sdafsdf"; //<-- THIS WORKS!!!
    *address = text2Copy;//WHY DOESN"T THIS WORK?
}

int main(){
    //just the string I will be using.
    char * text = "'CONVERT capitals TO lower CASE'";
    //print the string to show the original
    printf("%s\n",text);

    lowercase(&text,text);

    //This is where I want the value from the function to print out
    printf("%s\n",text);

    return 0;
}
```

If you could help me I would greatly appreciate it I am really confused and a bit annoyed at why this won't work. if you need me to explain it better just request it I hope I did enough already tho.

Thanks, Jake.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////edit//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Okay I have used all of your suggestions thank you :D
and now it currently works other than a weird bug that I don't know how to fix.
everything other than the first char gets turned into a lower case character.
what happens now -> "+onvert capitals to lower case" I don't know why the first character is doing that? anythoughts?

Here is the new code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*
----------------------------------------------
    CONVERTS UPPERCASE CHARACTERS TO LOWERCASE
----------------------------------------------
*/
void lowercase(char * address, char text2[]){
    // used in the for loop
    int inc;
    // used in the for loop
    int length = strlen(text2);

    for(inc = 0; inc <= length; inc++){
        //basicaly if character is a capital leter
        if(text2[inc] >= 'A' && text2[inc] <= 'Z'){
            //I plus 32 because each letter is 32 numbers away in 'ASCII'
            //therefore converting capital to lowercase
            text2[inc] += 32;
            //add one to help with indexing
            inctwo++;
        }
        //if the character is not a capital leter
        else{
            inctwo++;
        }
    }


    *address = text2;
}

int main(){
    //just the string I will be using.
    char text[] = "cONVERT capitals TO lower CASE";
    //print the string to show the original
    printf("%s\n",text);

    lowercase(&text,text);

    //This is where I want the value from the function to print out
    printf("%s\n",text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to modify a string literal, that is undefined behaviour, and often causes a segfault because string literals are (often) stored in read-only memory. It's a duplicate, let me search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [forbiddens in string literals in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691324/forbiddens-in-string-literals-in-c)

Comment: ahh ok thanks :D is there a way in which I can put it in read/write memory?

Comment: I think you can create dynamic string at run time `char  text2Copy[length];`. Change this to `char  text2Copy[20];` just for testing and see what do you get?

Comment: And the fix is `char text[] = "'CONVERT capitals TO lower CASE'";` to make it an array, so that you can modify the contents.

Comment: 2 parameters in your lowercase func is redundant.  Just pass by ref and you'll be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems. The first is that that your program should not even compile as you pass wrong types to your function. The second is that you try to modify a literal (and therefore constant) string.

For the second part, you could solve it very easily, by using an array instead:

```
char text[] = "CONVERT capitals TO lower CASE";
```

You also attempt to "return" a pointer to a local variable, and that will lead to undefined behavior as local variables are, well, local. Once a function returns the memory they occupied will be reused by other functions.

For the actual conversion function, it can be made **much** more simple than your attempt:

```
void lowercase(char *text)
{
    while (*text != '\0')
        *text = tolower(*text);
}
```

Comment: The conversion part is supposed to re write 'tolower()' and that is why I didn't use it. but also ok I corrected the problems with your suggestion but the string still doesn't change.

Comment: @user2509366: Have you changed `char* text` to `char text[]`?

Comment: 'You also attempt to "return" a pointer to a local variable, and that will lead to undefined behavior as local variables are, well, local. Once a function returns the memory they occupied will be reused by other functions.' but I have declared the char array in the main() so therefore the char array won't be reused in memory until the end of the program right? that is why I passed the address of 'text' into the function.

Comment: @user2509366 If you're using the [ASCII alphabet](http://www.asciitable.com/) (which almost all computers use today) you might notice some pattern between lower and upper case letters. Conversion from an uppercase letter to a lowercase letter is a simple addition. You can use a simple `if` statement to check if the character is a uppercase letter or not, and only do the addition if it's a uppercase letter.

Comment: @user2509366 But the variable `text2Copy` *is* local in the conversion function. And you want to "return" a pointer to that.

Comment: I thought "*address = text2Copy;" actually changed the variable that *address points to, to text2Copy. sorry mabye I am just retarted and don't understand it correctly I am still new