# Difference between array and pointer to string literal

Tags: c, memory-management, undefined-behavior

I am new to *C*, so it may be a dumb question. I was writing a piece of code like bellow:

```
char ar[]="test";

*(ar+1)='r';
```

this is working fine. But whenever I am doing it:

```
char *p="test";

*(p+1)="r";
```

this is giving *segmentation fault*. Can anyone please describe why second case is giving segmentation fault? explanation from memory point of view will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [forbiddens in string literals in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691324/forbiddens-in-string-literals-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second case `p` is pointing to a *string literal* and you are not allowed to modify a *string literal*, it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). From the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.5` *String literals* paragraph *6* (*emphasis mine*):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined**.

In the first case `ar` is an automatic variable and you are allowed to modify it since it not *const* qualified. The contents of the *string literal* are being copied during initialization or `ar`.

Answer (score 1):

In a c , whenever u store a string in an array, you could allow to change the content of the string . the reason for this, c store the content of string in a consecutive memory.

In the case of pointer , the pointer stored the starting address of the string and it assumes that would be constant . suppose , you try to change it. you get an undefined behavior , even the worse case is , you cant find it easily just because it wont be throw any error regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

the other aspect of your example 'r' == 114 (probably), while "r" == the address of the start of the const string "r" in your executable