# Conflicting types for 'reverse_string' function

Tags: c, string

I was using [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784417/reversing-a-string-in-c) as part of a program that needs to reverse a string. The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get the function to work. Here is the code I have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *test = "Testing";
  fputs(test, stdout);
  fputs(reverse_string(test), stdout);
}

char* reverse_string(char *str){
  char temp;
  size_t len = strlen(str) - 1;
  size_t i;
  size_t k = len;
  for(i = 0; i < (len +1)/2; i++){
    temp = str[k];
    str[k] = str[i];
    str[i] = temp;
    k--;
  }  
  return str;
}
```

I am getting an error that there is `conflicting types for 'reverse_string'`

Edit: For anyone wondering here is the code that works. See @chux's answer for an explanation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* reverse_string(char *str){
  char temp;
  size_t len = strlen(str) - 1;
  size_t i;
  size_t k = len;
  for(i = 0; i < (len +1)/2; i++){
    temp = str[k];
    str[k] = str[i];
    str[i] = temp;
    k--;
  }
  return str;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char test[] = "Testing";
  fputs(test, stdout);
  fputs(reverse_string(test), stdout);
}
```

Comment: You probably need to put reverse_string above main or declare it.  The compiler is probably assuming some things about the function.

Comment: If I run the same program with reverse_string declared above main I get a segmentation fault still.

Comment: @DannyDyla as chux and I mentioned in his answer, you can not modify a string literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not pass a `const char *` to a `char *`

```
char *test = "Testing";
fputs(reverse_string(test), ... // bad, attempting to change constant data.
// bad as  reverse_string() is assumed to return int, but fputs() expects char *

char* reverse_string(char *str) { // Bad, there's now a function conflict
```

Instead

```
char* reverse_string(char *str);  // Need to declare/define function first

char test[] = "Testing";
fputs(reverse_string(test), ... // good
```

[Edit]
You problem was well identified (missing function declaration) by others.  My suggestion takes care of the *next* problem.  In C, a missing declaration of a function will *assume* `int reverse_string(...)` which does not match `char* reverse_string(char *str)`.

[Edit]
As @Shafik Yaghmou suggests, modifying a string literal `char *test = "Testing"` will result in undefined behavior.  Hence the `char test[] = "Testing"` which initializes `test` with "Testing\0", but may be modified.

[Edit]
@GreenAsJade correctly points out OP's original error message is due to the assumed `int  reverse_string(...)` supplying an `int` to `s` in `int fputs(const char * s, FILE * stream);`

`char *test1 = "Testing"` is not the same thing as `char test2[] = "Testing"`.  `test1` becomes a `char *` with the size of a pointer.  The initial pointer value is to a string "Testing" located elsewhere in memory.  `test2` is a `char` array with size 8: length of "Testing" + 1 for '\0'.  The array `test2` is initialized with 'T', 'e', ... '\0' etc.

Comment: +1 you should also mention about forward declaring `reverse_string` and mentioning that modifying a string literal is undefined would be helpful.

Comment: Your answer suprised me.   I'm still none the wiser, because your first code block compiles fine (after you put the reverse_string(test) call inside main()).   I thought the now-deleted answers about predeclaring were the correct answer!

Comment: I was under the impression that `char *test = "Testing"` is the same thing as `char test[] = "Testing"`. Is that not true?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.   I didn't realise that c is so fussy about constness... I had thought of that as more of a C++ thing.   It's a long time since I've done hands on c programming though! (which is why I like reading these!)

Comment: @DannyDyla please see my answer to [Difference between array and pointer to string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20296674/1708801).

Comment: @chux: It is fair to say that it is not correct to say that you can't pass a const char * to a char *, in C?    I think that you can do it, you just might get a seg fault, if you try to modify it.   This is a little different.  One is a compile time certain error, the other a run time thing, that depends on the function body.

Comment: @ GreenAsJade Yes, your detail is closer (Type qualifiers §6.7.3 6).  Note: C had a long history before `const` arrived and thus allows `char *test = "Testing"` when it should be `const char *test = "Testing"`.  Had OP done so (and pre-declared the function), likely a warning about sending a `const char *` to `reverse_string(char *)` would have ensued.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

```
(h2hh)momerath:Documents mgregory$ cat test.c
char* reverse_string(char *str) {
  return str;
}

char *test = "Testing";

int main() {

  reverse_string(test);
}
(h2hh)momerath:Documents mgregory$ gcc test.c
(h2hh)momerath:Documents mgregory$
```

I think that the answer to the OP's question is that reverse_string has to be declared before being used, to be not int.

Comment: Thanks for the input - as the other, now deleted, answers appeared, I too saw additional code concerns.